# How to generate a report summary of messages that triggered a specific DSN code

Tags: linux, centos, grep, sendmail

I use Sendmail on CENTOS 5.x,
I hope this is a simple question. =) I need to generate a report summary of messages that triggered a specific DSN code.   For example:

```
Jan 11 07:43:34 server-example sendmail[12732]: p937blksdh3: to=<someuser@recipientdomain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=102537, relay=mta.recipientdomain.com. [12.34.56.78], dsn=5.7.1, stat=Service unavailable
```

Normally, I would just grep for this information (something like: `grep -i "dsn=5.7.1" /var/log/maillog`).  But the problem is that this only returns a line like above and doesn't tell me the sender of the message.

Ideally, I'm looking for a one-liner that can do the following:

1. Search sendmail maillog for specific DSN.
2. Identify the message-id for the email. (I'm guessing `awk '{print $}'` would be used?)
3. Return the message details for each (presumably grepping for the the message id retrieved from step 2).

Comment: For those of us who aren't specifically familiar with `sendmail`, it might help if you post a more complete set of log lines, and describe exactly what details you're paying attention to when you do this manually.  For example, in the line you've posted, is `p937blksdh3` the message-id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash

```
dsn=5.7.1
$ grep $dsn /var/log/maillog | awk '{print $6}' | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

returns:

```
p937blksdh3
```

Of the line you posted,  I'm guessing that is the message id?

OK, it's not one line. Then `grep` for that for message details, where are the message details kept?

Comment: Thanks.  That pointed me in the right direction.  The final one-liner I came up with is a variation of that and includes a for loop: `grep -i "dsn=5" /var/log/maillog | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/://' | while read -r x; do grep -i "$x" /var/log/maillog; done`